# Set work order status to release with workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite

How can i set the work order status to release using a workflow?
I have tried the set field value action however it seems that the work order status is not an option.

Comment: I do not have the "Work Order" record in my environment so I could not test exactly.  From memory if a field is not listed on the list; it simply is not available for "set Field value" via workflow.  As an alternative solution you could set the field value via SuiteScript.  The specific function depends on when/how you want to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

If your choice of doing that using a workflow. Please create a workflow action script to set the work order status.